Provide an ε-δ proof for the following limit
I am attempting to provide a sufficient $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof for the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x^3-8}{x^2-4}=3.$$
Here is what I have so far: for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$\left|\frac{x^3-8}{x^2-4}-3\right|<\epsilon\text{ if }0<|x-2|<\delta.$$
However, when I simplify the expression to
$$\left|\frac{x^3-8}{x^2-4}-3\right|=\left|x-3+\frac{4}{x+2}\right|$$
I am confused on what to do next.
I also know that $|x-3|\geq|x-2|-1$, but is this useful to my proof? Thanks.

First notice that both $x^3-8$ and $x^2-4$ have a root at $x=2$.
Moreover, we may express $x^3-8=(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)$ and $x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2)$.
Therefore, if $x\neq 2$ and $x\neq -2$, we have $$\frac{x^3-8}{x^2-4}=\dfrac{x^2+2x+4}{x+2},$$
and so
$$\frac{x^3-8}{x^2-4}-3=\dfrac{x^2+2x+4}{x+2}-3=\dfrac{x^2-x-2}{x+2}=(x-2)\dfrac{x+1}{x+2}$$
We want to bound $$|x-2|\dfrac{|x+1|}{|x+2|}$$
If $|x-2|<1$ and $|x-2|<\dfrac{3\epsilon}{4}$ then $1<x<3$, so $|x+1|<4$ and $|x+2|>3$.
Thus, $\dfrac{|x+1|}{|x+2|}<\dfrac{4}{3}$ and $|x-2|\dfrac{|x+1|}{|x+2|}<\dfrac{3\epsilon}{4}\cdot\dfrac{4}{3}=\epsilon$.
For this reason, taking $\delta<\min\{1,3\epsilon/4\}$ finishes the proof.

This makes a lot of sense, but I am confused why we are able to say | x - 2 | < 1. Where does the 1 come from? Is this just a choice?

Yes, it is just a choice. You could choose $|x-2|<2$ and then we would have $\frac{|x+1|}{|x+2|}<\frac{5}{2}$. Instead of $3\epsilon/4$ we would need $2\epsilon/5$.
